# Several "orphaned" printers

Tags: printing, windows-server-2012

One of my RDS users has 3 of the same printer...

[image]

Sry it's in Danish.

If he logs onto another RDS server, everything is fine (he only has 1), so I guess it's something on the server (it's not in the AD - it lists only 1 server).

I've tried to delete the users profile on that particular server, but it didn't help.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you keep tagging your questions with Server 2008 AND 2012, when you're only talking about 2012? does this happen for just this user, or any user? Have you tried simply deleting and recreating the printer on the server yet?

Comment: What are we looking at here? Is this the client side? Those three printer icons is what you have problems with?

Comment: Why is this a problem? If you can print, and it doesn't cause business downtime, leave it alone. It's not worth it. Just set the default printer and carry on with your work. There's nothing to see, just look away, it's not like you will be spending hours and hours in Control Panel. I wouldn't bother with this at all. But if you can't let be, I advise that you start troubleshooting from the client side of things.

Comment: @Techie007: Because there's 10 times as many users monitoring 2008 and in many cases my problems also exists in 2008. Yes, if I delete the printer and create it again it will add another, so it will list 4 printers in printer properties.

Comment: @sammyg:: Well if the specific user logs into this RDS server, he gets this problem. If he logs into another RDS server, he doesn't have this problem. So it must be something at the specific server. I've tried deleting his profile on this server, but it didn't help. I've tried logging another RDS user into this server and he didn't have the problem.

Comment: @sammyg: problem is, that the user can't print at all on this server.

Comment: It works from another RDS server using the same printer? It could be a version mismatch. That often causes strange behavior like this. Check RDS server and client versions. It might be a bug as well, we can't rule that out.